# How to get the day of tomorrow from database using codeginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with compression date in codeginiter.
Example today is 2014-08-14 but I want to select data from database where date=tomorrow.

Is anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
$tomorrow_time = strtotime("+1 day");
$tomorrow_date = date('Y-m-d', $tomorrow_time);
```

now compare this date in your database;

Answer (score 0):

```
 $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow');
 echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitor, when you add some explanation to your intension.

Answer (score 0):

in sql

```
where date = DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1DAY)
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitor, when you add some explanation to your intension.